# Cannot receive a value on Raspberry pi 3 from Android via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I am new to Programming with Java, and I am trying to send some value from 'Blueterm' application on Android and receive it on my Raspberry pi 3 via Bluetooth. Already raspberrypi3 has built in bluetooth and I am able to pair the 2 devices but I am not able to connect them and don't know how to start with the Java code. I hava tried ConnectedThread and AcceptThread but no progress, so if anyone could help me with this.

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.bluetooth.*;
import android.bluetooth.*;

public class AcceptThread extends Thread {
 private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
 private UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    public AcceptThread() {
     BluetoothAdapter Badp= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (Badp == null) {
       // Device does not support Bluetooth
     System.out.println("Bluetooth Not Supported");
    }
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
        // because mmServerSocket is final
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = Badp.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }
 
    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                try {
     mmServerSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
 
    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    private void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        
        //acceptThread.cancel();
    }
 

}
```

Comment: Could you show some code you've attempted?

Comment: Yeah I have inserted the AcceptThread in the post.